# How to execute 'NOT IN' clause in Execute SQL processor in nifi

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to execute the following query using 'ExecuteSQL' processor in Apache nifi.

```
INSERT INTO SampleDB VALUES (${rno}, '${tno}', '${tval}', '${lotno}', '${datval}') WHERE ${rno} NOT IN (SELECT rno FROM SampleDB);
```

Here the `${rno}` is obtained as flow file attribute.

The following error is obtained on execution:

> ExecuteSQL[id=01781107-63a4-1204-8110-6b19db3d5ffc] Unable to execute SQL select query INSERT INTO LimsOnCloud VALUES (1, 'CTG123 ', 'ITM123 ', '123 ', '5 ') WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT rno FROM SampleDB); for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=93db20b2-5f9f-4521-ac42-11239abb94c2,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1615281573937-132, container=default, section=132], offset=168254, length=152],offset=0,name=098a8ad2-0dc9-4564-a242-8b4855b619b2,size=152] due to Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.; routing to failure: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Not able to figure out where the error lies or what is the better way to achieve this.

Comment: The query is simply invalid. Apart from that, DON'T use string interpolation to construct SQL queries. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. What if one of those fields contained `'); Drop table Users;--` ? Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: The syntax you are looking for is `INSERT SampleDB (col1, col2, col3...) SELECT @param1, @param2, @param3.... WHERE ...` and **use parameters**

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You have a **table** named `SampleDB`??

Answer (score 0):

- **You should be using proper parameterized queries.**
- To use a `WHERE` like that, you need `SELECT`.
- You should also specify the column names to insert into explicitly.
- `NOT IN` falls down in the face of nullables, so favour `NOT EXISTS` instead.

```sql
INSERT INTO SampleDB
    (rno, tno, tval, lotno, datval)
SELECT @rno, @tno, @tval, @lotno, @datval
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM SampleDB
    WHERE rno = @rno
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Error is being thrown because it tries for find a column named 1 in your table, so Instead of the above, try this

```
INSERT INTO SampleDB SELECT ${rno}, '${tno}', '${tval}', '${lotno}', '${datval}' 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SampleDB WHERE rno = ${rno});
```

Comment: Also invalid, and uses interpolation, not parameters

Comment: @Charlieface, the exception was due to the incorrect placing of the parameters, so I just re-arranged the same

Comment: `INSERT...VALUES...WHERE...` is not valid, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15